# Quicker boot w/Bluetooth and Python

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, boot, hardware, bluetooth

I am creating an embedded display to be used as a heads up display. I want the system to be up and running as soon as possible. The basics I need to be running is the GUI of X to run a Python script and I need Bluetooth enabled as well so I can communicate with an obd2 device over Bluetooth. What are some good ways of cutting down boot times whilst keeping X, Python, and Bluetooth. I would also prefer to keep networking to ssh in to work on if need be.

Thanks, Brett

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we will be editing our `/boot/cmdline.txt` for the goal of speeding up our boot time.

`$ sudo nano /boot/cmdline.txt`

We will change the content to :

`dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=serial0,115200 console=tty3 loglevel=0 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes rootwait logo.nologo quiet splash vt.global_cursor_default=0`

The important bits are as follows:

`loglevel=0
quiet
splash
logo.nologo
console=tty3
vt.global_cuursor_default=0`

Please make sure that all these are seperated with a space and all placed on a single line.

Additional work can be used to quicken things up:
We need to tell dmesg to be quiet

`sudo nano /etc/rc.local`

add `dmesg --console-off` just above `exit 0`

Change the auto login in systemd, hides login message:

`sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/autologin\@.service`

Find the line:

`ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty --autologin pi --noclear %I $TERM`

and change it to the following:

`ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty --skip-login --noclear --noissue --login-options "-f pi" %I $TERM`

Next we will remove the kernel version from showing when you auto-login

`sudo nano /etc/pam.d/login`

Find the line:

`session    optional   pam_exec.so type=open_session stdout /bin/uname -snrvm`

then change it to the following:

`session    optional   pam_exec.so type=open_session stdout`

Now we will a `.hushlogin`

`touch ~/.hushlogin`

or we can remove the message of the day aka MOTD. This is an alternative to `touch ~/.hushlogin`

`sudo update-rc.d motd remove`

And with that we are finished!

This is great for a headless display as we dont need to see any of that text anyway. This is also great to use if you are running a python GUI on boot. This will login and then display your GUI once fully booted.

This was quoted from my blog : https://bareinhard.github.io/2017/02/10/Raspberry-Pi-Faster-Boot.html